# How to resolve these errors?

Tags: reactjs

I was just setting up the react setup but during that I found these errors and I don't know how to resolve this ...

This is for reactjs, with nodejs.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "REACTjs-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "SOME BASICS",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p && cp src/index.html dist/index.html"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react"
  ],
  "author": "XYZ",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.36.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6"
  }
}
```

I was looking for the solution

[image]

Comment: We can't help you until you upload full log.

Comment: Include the full log from your console

Comment: What actually you want to do ?

Comment: I think it is an issue with your webpack installation and try to install it globally using `npm install webpack -g` and all its dependencies. Otherwise, try to pass your local webpack from node modules to your **npm run build** command like `node_modules\.bin\webpack`.

Comment: Okay, I will share the entire log for the same.